# Searching an array In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I been getting two arrays and merging them and then looking for a certain value under `name` but can't seem to get it working

```
$temp = [
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Abigail'],
];

 $temp1 = [
     ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
     ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
];

$ggg = array_merge($temp,$temp1);
```

Comment: I don't see any searching code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [contains()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-contains) method of a collection. The schema:

```
collect($array1)               // Create a collection from the first array
    ->merge($array2)           // merge it with the second array
    ->contains($key, $value);  // returns boolean
```

Your code:

```
$temp = [
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Abigail'],
];

$temp1 = [
     ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
     ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
];

collect($temp)->merge($temp1)->contains('name', 'Taylor');  // true
collect($temp)->merge($temp1)->contains('name', 'Jane');  // false
```

If you want to get the items who are matching the criteria, use [where()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where):

```
$result = collect($temp)->merge($temp1)->where('name', 'Taylor');
```

This will return:

```
Collection {#465 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "Taylor"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "Taylor"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "Taylor"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use print_r($ggg) to print the resulting array. Referring to the name part you should use $ggg[0]['name'] for example. Not sure what is your final goal for merging the 2 arrays, do you want an array with all 4 elements ? The way you are doing it you will end up with only 2 elements, index 0 of $temp1 will overwrite index 0 of $temp, same thing with index 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and maybe this will help you.

```
$temp = [
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Abigail'],
];

$temp1 = [
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
];

$ggg = array_merge($temp,$temp1);

foreach ($ggg as $key) {
  echo "ID: ".$key['id']."<br>";
  echo "NAME: ".$key['name']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like below. Since you tagged this as Laravel I've done it with laravel specific code, but it would be possible to use native PHP too.

```
$temp = [
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Abigail'],
];

$temp1 = [
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Taylor'],
];

$item = collect($temp)->merge($temp1)->first(function ($item) {
    return $item['name'] == 'Taylor';
});
```